# oc cluster up command cannot find components such as metrics, logging, service-catalog

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

Thanks a lot for your help in advance. I am able to run all-in-one openshift origin v3.11 on my local virtualbox VM.

https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/release-3.11/docs/cluster_up_down.md

Followed by this document, I learned that I am able to install additional components such as --metrics, --logging, --service-catalog, but I am trying to append this argument in oc cluster up, the usage said these options are not available, such as:

```
[root@master openshift]# oc cluster up --metrics
Error: unknown flag: --metrics


Usage:
  oc cluster up [flags]

Examples:
  # Start OpenShift using a specific public host name
  oc cluster up --public-hostname=my.address.example.com

Options:
      --base-dir='': Directory on Docker host for cluster up configuration
      --enable=[*]: A list of components to enable.  '*' enables all on-by-default components, 'foo' enables the component named 'foo', '-foo' disables the component named 'foo'.
All components: automation-service-broker, centos-imagestreams, persistent-volumes, registry, rhel-imagestreams, router, sample-templates, service-catalog, template-service-broker, web-console
Disabled-by-default components: automation-service-broker, rhel-imagestreams, service-catalog, template-service-broker
      --forward-ports=false: Use Docker port-forwarding to communicate with origin container. Requires 'socat' locally.
      --http-proxy='': HTTP proxy to use for master and builds
      --https-proxy='': HTTPS proxy to use for master and builds
      --image='openshift/origin-${component}:${version}': Specify the images to use for OpenShift
      --no-proxy=[]: List of hosts or subnets for which a proxy should not be used
      --public-hostname='': Public hostname for OpenShift cluster
      --routing-suffix='': Default suffix for server routes
      --server-loglevel=0: Log level for OpenShift server
      --skip-registry-check=false: Skip Docker daemon registry check
      --write-config=false: Write the configuration files into host config dir

Use "oc options" for a list of global command-line options (applies to all commands).

[root@master openshift]#
```

The same also fail when I append --logging, --service-catalog.

Note that, if I remove the argument, oc cluster up can startup successful. Should I install something that I missed?

Comment: The ability to deploy those components with ``oc cluster up`` was not always reliable so understand the ability to start them was likely being removed. How ``oc cluster up`` was implemented was also changed a lot in most recent version, so they could have disappeared because of that.

Comment: Thanks Graham. Does this mean the github document was wrong (at least not sync?) I think v3.11 is the latest version and it supposed to be up-to-date with the document. Am I the first person to ask this question? I think this is a common question. How does other people deployed those components? Do you imply those components previously exists but get removed in most recent releases? Sounds doesn't make sense :)

Comment: All I can say is that aggregated logging and metrics never reliably worked in any version of ``oc cluster up`` I tried. Most of the time they wouldn't even start. If you want to have these features, you are better off starting out by trying to do single node cluster installation from scratch yourself. Do not use ``oc cluster up.``. Perhaps look at https://blog.openshift.com/installing-okd-3-10-on-a-single-host/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. Actually I'm just out of curiosity. It doesn't matter when I don't have these features. Always appreciate your speedy response. We can close this discussion. :)

Comment: @TerryHu - did you every find a way to enable logging or metrics in `oc cluster up`?